# Tornado Cookies

Tags: php, python, apache, cookies, tornado

I am using Apache and PHP as my front-end server and Tornado as my 
back-end to handle my requests. When allowing a user to login I want 
to create cookies for the username and password. If I do it as 
follows:

```
self.set_cookie('emailaddress', email_address, domain='mydomain.com', expires=None, path='/', expires_days=expire_d)
self.set_cookie('password', newpass, domain='mydomain.com', expires=None, path='/', expires_days=expire_d)
```

Nothing is created. But if I do:

```
self.set_cookie('emailaddress', email_address) 
self.set_cookie('password', newpass)
```

It works. But than even though the cookies which I can see from 
Firefox and Firebug but PHP on my front-end doesn't recognize them. 
Also I know its not from cross-domain because I have my Tornado server 
Proxy through Apache.

Comment: Okay so it seems that the problems lays within defining the domain. Not sure why, but I'd like to make it a global cookie for my domain so subdomains can use it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems like the problem is related to subdomains if you are using them to route between Tornado and PHP, without details on this it's hard to tell how to fix it.

But in general maybe it will be a good idea to just map Tornado to some relative url on a main domain and do not mess with subdomains?

*P.S.: storing login/password pairs in cookies in plain text is not secure, I'd recomend to use unique session id mapped to users via common database between PHP and Tornado.*

Comment: Yeah I ended up figuring it out. I'd say Tornado still has some bugs because after completely shutting the Tornado Server down and starting it back up instead of restarting it solved the Cookie issue. And I ended up changing the login credentials, storing the user id, creating a session token id, and a storing part of the ip address in the cookies and comparing them to the database. Seems to be working pretty good that away.